# padding in asp.net

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

Is there a function to append padding digits to the left of a digit.I want to form a 3 digit number, so when the value is '3' i need to make it '003'

e.g in php we have

```
$m_ccode=str_pad($m_casecode,3,"0",str_pad_left);
```

same i want to convert in asp.net c#. How can i do it, i have numeric value stored in string 's'

```
String s = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string variant1 = "3".PadLeft(3, '0'); // if you have a string
string variant2 = 3.ToString("000"); // if you have a number
```

In your case you need to unbox your int if the numeric value is an `int`

```
String s = ((int)DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value).ToString("000");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
String s = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3, '0');
```